# Верстка jsp страницы в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, html, jsp

Не знаю, как правильно написать заголовок, ибо не до конца понимаю как кратко описать то, что мне необходимо сделать. 
Есть jsp страница c html кодом, в этом коде у меня, например, navbar и sidebar есть, могу ли я как-то эти 2 bar'a вытянуть в отдельные файлы, чтобы потом просто кодключать их к jsp странице, чтобы не переписывать на каждую jsp страницу код от navbar and sidebar? Делал когда-то давно нечто подобное в php, реализуемо ли это в java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаёшь новую jsp страницу, с элементами, которые необходимо подгрузить к текущей странице и вставляешь её таким образом `<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>` в нужном месте

```
<html>
    <head>
       <!--head-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!